# Disable editing of a text field

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to start by saying this is my first project and I am trying hard to find answers myself before posting here. I thought I had found the code to accomplish this. I have no errors but when I run, the field is still editable. So, how can I disable editing of my field when the rule I have set is true?

```
if sport.count == 1 {

        enterSport.text = sport[0] as String //need to convert to a string
        enterSport.editing; false //do not allow editing

    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
```

I have defined the array previously so the if statement is true. Thank you for you assistance.

Comment: I don't know Swift but shouldn't that be `enterSport.editing = false`?

Comment: @Leonardo Don't edit the code of the question like that. By fixing the problem in the question you hide the point of the question.

Comment: I started with .editing = false and I get an error "Cannot assign to the result of this expression". That is why I tried editing; false with no errors. I changed back to .editing = false and I am back to the error.

Comment: Try `enterSport.editing = NO` instead

Comment: @duncanc4 I had tried that also. Sorry I didn't list all the things I had tried. At this point I don't even recall them all. The code I asked about is all I could find that did not return an error. (but it also doesn't work). Is there something I need to do to the text field in the story board to make this work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`enterSport.userInteractionEnabled = false` instead of `editing`.

`editing` is a read-only property to indicate if the field is currently being edited or not.

**Swift 5:** 
`enterSport.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: Or `enterSport.enabled = false`.

Comment: Right, the possible side effect of using `enabled` being that it may affect the actual look of the view (such as gray it out). I don't remember offhand if that happens with a `UITextField` though.

Comment: Success! Thank you all for your suggestions. They all help me to look at new ideas.

Answer (score 4):

To summarize the answers and comments above:

editing is a readonly property. You can't set it.

If it's a UITextView, it has an editable property which you can set to false.

If it's a UITextField, you need to use the enabled property or the userInteractionEnabled property. Either of those will prevent editing. As

Answer (score 4):

With Swift 3 Apple changed the property `userInteractionEnabled` to `isUserInteractionEnabled`.

The code looks like this:

`textfield.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: Please edit your answer. *Which* property name was changed? Provide the correct code in order to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way of avoiding keyboard appearing

You can set an **UITapGestureRecognizer** like this:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.textFieldEditing))
self.enterSport.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

and

```
@objc func textFieldEditing() {
    self.enterSport.resignFirstResponder()
    
}
```